# An unknow login page show up

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to understand this spring-boot project:[hbs-spring-boot-jpa-mysql-thymeleaf-security](https://github.com/MarcinU2K/hbs-spring-boot-jpa-mysql-thymeleaf-)
In the HbsController the code is
[image]

As I know when I input the `localhost:8080/hbs`, I should see the index page right? but I can only see this
[image]
And I look into the project
[image]
 I can't find the login page? where is it? please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the SecurityConfig you might have the /hbs mapping with authorisation required.

in this example from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable()
      .authorizeRequests()
      .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
      .antMatchers("/anonymous*").anonymous()
      .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll()
      .anyRequest().authenticated()
      .and()
      .formLogin()
      .loginPage("/login.html")
      .loginProcessingUrl("/perform_login")
      .defaultSuccessUrl("/homepage.html", true)
      //.failureUrl("/login.html?error=true")
      .failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler())
      .and()
      .logout()
      .logoutUrl("/perform_logout")
      .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
      .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessHandler());
}
```

".antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")" forces the acces to only "ADMIN" users and redirects them to /login

try to modify your configuration class that implements WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it will work

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because there is spring boot security implemented/included in the pom file/project: https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/

You can see the spring security configuration in the class "SpringSecurity.java" in the folder "security". You can modify it there or look up what the credentials are.